# Gatsby.js (React) - graphql query in gatsby-browser.js

Tags: reactjs, gatsby

I have a plugin TypeWriting in Gatsby.js (React). It looks like this:

```
/* file: gatsby-browser.js */
const typeWriting = () => {
  new Typewriter('#intro-typing', {
    strings: ['Drupal', 'WordPress', 'OpenCart'],
  });
}
export const onInitialClientRender = () => {
  typeWriting();
}
```

I want to set for "string" - own array from graphql query

How I can work with graphql query in *gatsby-browser.js*?

Answer (score 0):

`gatsby-browser.js` is a file that lets you respond to actions within the browser, and wrap your site in additional components. The Gatsby Browser API gives you many options for interacting with the [client-side of Gatsby](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/glossary#client-side). So I don't think that you can trigger, outside any API or method, any kind of GraphQL query.

If you want that `strings` array to be "automated" you can use [environment variables](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/how-to/local-development/environment-variables/) and get place it as values of the array.